# Cannot use png images from VUE public folder

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a static asset - png image. I was able to use it like:

```
<img class="navbar-brand" id="navbar-logo" src="@/assets/logo.png">
```

But I need it to be possible to replace after deployment. When I put image in public folder and use an absolute path vue application not shows image.

```
<img class="navbar-brand" id="navbar-logo" src="/logo.png">
```

The img tag presents on page and browser executes http call for image. The response code is 200 but response body is empty. The image file stored in public folder, which is in root folder of vue application. Actually even if I put in src attribute the name of image which not exist I get a 200 response code, which is strange.

[image: Image not shown]

[image: The HTTP call executed successfully]

I also have a router in my application and it seems to be working fine, but I not sure can it cause the problem or not:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/:dataset([^/0-9]+?)',
      name: 'introduction',
      component: Introduction
    },
    {
      path: '/:dataset([^/0-9]+?)/introduction',
      name: 'introduction',
      component: Introduction
    },
    {
      path: '/:dataset([^/0-9]+?)/sample-data',
      name: 'sample-data',
      component: SampleData
    },
    {
      path: '/404',
      component: NotFound
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      component: NotFound
    }
  ]
})
```

I run application on my workstation with

```
npm run dev
```

The vue version is:

```
front@1.0.0 /home/pm/git/showroom/front
└── vue@2.6.11
```

Please help to show image from public folder.

Comment: What project is this? It could be related with webpack config? Cause even with default vue project when u change the directory to public, it's working

Comment: I started this project about couple month ago. I do not know I did anything I would expect to cause this problem. About webpack - I not know much about it. Could it be possible to debug this problem somehow. May be I could turn on some log messages or something like that?